# Найти ошибку в процедуре p3: не меняет правильно строки в двумерном массиве A

Tags: массивы, delphi, процедуры

Все делает правильно, но подводит процедура p3: не меняет строку с максимальным элементом главной диагонали массива А со строкой с минимальным элементом той же главной диагонали.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Menus, AxCtrls, OleCtrls, VCF1, StdCtrls, OleCtnrs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    OleContainer1: TOleContainer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    N11: TMenuItem;
    N21: TMenuItem;
    N31: TMenuItem;
    N41: TMenuItem;
    N51: TMenuItem;
    F1Book1: TF1Book;
    F1Book2: TF1Book;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure N21Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure N11Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure N31Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure N41Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure N51Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
type
a1=array[1..9] of array[1..9] of real;
a2=array[1..9] of real;
const
n=9;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  k,l,i,j: integer;
  a:a1;
  g:a2;
  max,min: real;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure p1(var mass:a1);//p1(a)
  var x,y: integer;
  begin
    for x:=1 to n do
      for y:=1 to n do
      If x>y then mass[x,y]:=0.37-sqr(y-3)
      else mass[x,y]:=0.98*x-sqrt(3.24*y);
end;

function f2(mass:a1; var m1,m2:real):string;//f2(a,min,max,k,l)
  var x:integer;
  begin
    m1:=mass[1,1];
    m2:=mass[1,1];
    for x:=1 to n do
    begin
    If mass[x,x]<m1 then m1:=mass[x,x];
    If mass[x,x]>m2 then m2:=mass[x,x];
    end;
    f2:='Минимальное значение главной диагонали равно '+format('%5.2f',[m1])+#13+'Максимальное значение главной диагонали равно '+format('%5.2f',[m2]);
end;

procedure p3(mass:a1; var w,z:integer);//p3(a,k,l,i,j,min,max)
  var v,m1,m2: real;
  x,y:integer;
  begin
    m1:=mass[1,1];
    m2:=mass[1,1];
    for x:=1 to n do
    begin
    If mass[x,x]<m1 then begin m1:=mass[x,x]; w:=x; end;
    If mass[x,x]>m2 then begin m2:=mass[x,x]; z:=x; end;
    end;
    for y:=1 to n do
      begin
        v:=mass[w,y];
        mass[w,y]:=mass[z,y];
        mass[z,y]:=v;
      end;
end;

procedure p4(mass:a1; var mass2:a2);//p4(a,g)
  var y:integer;
  begin
    for y:=1 to n do
      mass2[y]:=mass[6,y];
end;

procedure p5(var mass2: a2);//p5(g)
  var imin,u:integer;
  buf: real;
  y: integer;
  begin
    for y:=1 to n-1 do
      begin
        imin:=y;
        for u:=y+1 to n do
          if mass2[u]>mass2[imin] then imin:=u;
          buf:=mass2[y];
          mass2[y]:=mass2[imin];
          mass2[imin]:=buf;
      end;
end;

procedure TForm1.N21Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
p1(a);
label1.Caption:=f2(a,min,max);
end;

procedure TForm1.N11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
p1(a);
for i:=1 to n do
for j:=1 to n do
f1book1.NumberRC[i,j]:=a[i,j];
end;

procedure TForm1.N31Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
p1(a);
p3(a,k,l);
//f1book2.TextRC[1,1]:='Обработанная матрица';
for i:=1 to n do
for j:=1 to n do
f1book2.NumberRC[i,j]:=a[i,j];
end;

procedure TForm1.N41Click(Sender: TObject);
var str: string;
begin
p1(a);
p3(a,k,l);
p4(a,g);
str:='';
for j:=1 to n do
str:=str+format('%5.2f',[g[j]])+'  ';
label2.Caption:='X = ('+str+')';
end;

procedure TForm1.N51Click(Sender: TObject);
var str2: string;
begin
p1(a);
p3(a,k,l);
p4(a,g);
p5(g);
for j:=1 to n do
str2:=str2+format('%5.2f',[g[j]])+'  ';
label3.Caption:='преобразованная матрица'+#13+'X = ('+str2+')';
end;

end.
```

Comment: Такую простыню никто не будет читать. Отформатируйте код и приведите только ту часть, в которой, по-вашему, проблема.

Comment: @almisl999, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Переменные z, v должны быть проинициализированы аналогично m1, m2.

Пример на вот такой матрице:

```
5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 3
```

Начальный элемент будет равен 5, то есть ваши m1 и m2. В условие

```
If mass[x,x]>m2 then begin m2:=mass[x,x]; z:=x; end;
```

Ваш код не войдет никогда, соответственно индекс максимального элемента не изменится. Правильно наверное так:

```
procedure p3(mass:a1; var w,z:integer);//p3(a,k,l,i,j,min,max)
  var v,m1,m2: real;
  x,y:integer;
  begin
    m1:=mass[1,1];
    w := 1;
    m2:=mass[1,1];
    z := 1;
    for x:=1 to n do
    begin
    If mass[x,x]<m1 then begin m1:=mass[x,x]; w:=x; end;
    If mass[x,x]>m2 then begin m2:=mass[x,x]; z:=x; end;
    end;
    for y:=1 to n do
      begin
        v:=mass[w,y];
        mass[w,y]:=mass[z,y];
        mass[z,y]:=v;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Сейчас у меня почему-то выдает первичный массив, который получен из первой процедуры.

Comment: Ах, нет, спасибо большое, я уже сам нашел ошибку. Перед mass:a1 тоже нужен var.